# Assets are loaded via FFI module in flutter

Tags: android, c++, flutter, dart, ffi

Develop a flutter mobile app that loads models of assets in flutter by cpp files with dart's FFI.

I hope to develop a flutter app to do deep learning related work, and now I have written my inference code in c++. I have a couple of model parameter files in the assets folder and I want to pass the file contents (or path) in assets to the backend for processing.

I've added assets to the `pubspec.yaml` file, and in flutter I can open it properly with `rootBundle`. Some of the tricky things I've found are that dart doesn't seem to be able to directly open files in assets by passing a string of file paths. I wrote the interface using dart's FFI module, called the `init_model_from_file` function, and the runtime showed that the `model_path` file could not be found. for example:

```cpp
void init_model_from_file(const std::string &model_path) {
std::ifstream file(model_path, std::ios::binary); 
if (file.is_open()) { 
    char buffer[100]; 
    file.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    file.close(); 
} else {
    std::cerr << "Error opening the file!" << std::endl;
// Opens and loads the contents of the model by path
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images), during a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called the asset bundle that apps read from at runtime. So whether the model file can never be found and loaded by the CXX source file?

I tried reading the entire contents of the model file in flutter and passing a pointer to the file contents to the cpp source file. Initialize `My_Predictor` after opening model in memory and return a pointer to that recognizer for later use. Due to returned `My_Predictor` has a very complicated inheritance, I don't know if I can directly use a `Pointer<Uint8>` pointer to define the return value in Dart, and the contents of the file could not be retrieved by the function.

Here's my dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart' as ffi;
import 'dart:typed_data';

typedef InitModelFunction = Pointer<Void> Function(Pointer<ffi.Utf8>);
typedef InitModel = Pointer<Void> Function(Pointer<ffi.Utf8>);

const String _libName = 'mylib';
final DynamicLibrary _dylib = DynamicLibrary.open('lib$_libName.so');
Function initModel =
    _dylib.lookupFunction<InitModelFunction, InitModel>('init_model_from_buffer');

ByteData detModelContent = await rootBundle.load("assets/models/myModel.nb");;

Pointer<Uint8> detModelContentPtr =
    ffi.malloc.allocate<Uint8>(detModelContent.lengthInBytes);
print('detModelContent size in dart: ${detModelContent.lengthInBytes}');

ffiPointer = initModel(detModelContentPtr);
ffi.malloc.free(detModelContentPtr);
```

Here is the c++ code:

```cpp
extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) __attribute__((used)) 
My_Predictor *init_model_from_buffer(char *c_det_model_content);

My_Predictor *init_model_from_buffer(char *c_det_model_content)
{
  std::string det_model_content = c_det_model_content;
  LOGI("detModelContent size in cpp: %d", det_model_content.size());
  // Read the model from memory
  My_Predictor my_predictor = new My_Predictor();
  my_predictor->init(det_model_content, rec_model_content, cls_model_content);
  return my_predictor;
}
```

After running it, it shows:

```bash
detModelContent size in dart: 884390
detModelContent size in cpp: 0
```

I think it is more reasonable to pass the file path as a string. If can't do that, is reading the model file in dart and passing it to the backend like above the right thing to do?

thx.